# What show is this? White robes & black robes with glowing spheres

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find information on a show I watched as a child. For context, this would have been on Australian TV, probably somewhere in the vicinity of 1990-1993.

I'm pretty sure it was only 1 or 2 parts, and showed on ABC, so might have been part of some kind of omnibus/anthology show. A couple of kids (brother & sister?) are fighting, and get transported to a mysterious island inhabited by two tribes - the white-robed "follow the rules" group and the black-robed "do what you like" group. The tribes each have a glowing (spherical? hemispherical?) Macguffin and plan to steal/destroy the other tribes'. I think the kids either visit both tribes or decide to join different ones, but then for whatever reason the tribes both decide to attack, and the kids realise that both tribes are in the wrong, and the answer is to join the two Macguffins together, which makes the tribes merge as well into a single grey-robed group.

**EDIT** Some additional details, from half-formed memories as well as based on comments:

- I seem to remember some scenes took place inside a giant tent/marquee. I think that might have been where the white-robed tribe lived.
- In general, production values were pretty low - I think there were about four locations seen in the entire thing, being the homes of the two tribes, some external location on the island (possibly on a cliff), and the home where the two children started.
- I'm pretty sure it was Australian, but I can't guarantee it.
- Having looked through the Wikipedia list of children's shows currently on ABC TV it definitely isn't there, I have not found any clues to it in the first few pages of the list of past shows but that's a much longer slog (especially since that list isn't separated by genre).

Comment: Somehow I'm reminded of _The Dark Crystal_, but that isn't it. Sounds definitely inspired by it though.

Comment: Production values were probably a tiny fraction of those in The Dark Crystal.

Comment: Any info on the actors?

Comment: Also, check [this list of Australian kid's TV shows aired by the ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_ABC_Television#Children.27s_programs).

Comment: It could be *[The New Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Tomorrow)*. But the plot points aren't exact.

Comment: Definitely not The New Tomorrow, or even The Tribe. About 10 years too late for that.

Comment: You could try clicking on all the years it might be on [this fairly comprehensive list of "telefantasies"](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/john.seymour1/telefantasylist/whatistelefantasy.html), they have an "other countries" section which includes shows from Australia.

Comment: I found this on Buzzfeed buzzfeed.com/jennaguillaume/… but nothing on this list seems to match the description. I also found this list on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Australian_children%27s_television_series. I know Wiki references aren't the best as far as this site goes, but do any of these sound familiar?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Your list is probably the closest I've gotten to finding it - none of the shows listed matches, but there were one or two omnibus shows in there that could potentially contain the episode (and also the list reminded me of a bunch of other childhood shows, which was a great nostalgia trip). If you want to put it as an answer I'll happily award you the bounty.